# SAML integration of WSO2 with OpenAM

Tags: wso2, integration, saml, openam

Can WSO2 APIM SAML authenticated using Forgerock OpenAM.
I followed WSO2 documentation and few blogs but still wasn't able to achieve this.
I want the WSO2 APIM URL to be redirected to Forgerock OpenAM and once I authenticate using the OpenAM user I would be redirected back to WSO2 and I would be logged in as Forgerock user.I had even created same user with same password under WSO2 so that Forgerock OpenAM user can be logged in once the SAML works but it didn't work for me.

Comment: We cannot help you without a better context...

Comment: you want to configure store/publisher of apim login to SAML ?

Comment: I want to configure carbon,publisher & store using SAML and I want to use forgerock openam as IAM solution.